# Opencv cascade classifier with SVM as weak learner

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, libsvm, cascade-classifier

I'm working on a project related to people detection. I successfully implemented both an HOG SVM based classifier (with libSVM) and a cascade classifier (with opencv). The svm classifier works really good, i tested over a number of videos and it is correctly detecting people with really a few false positive and a few false negative; problem here is the computational time: nearly 1.2-1.3 sec over the entire image and 0.2-0.4 sec over the foreground patches; since i'm working on a project that must be able to work in nearly real-time environment, so i switched to the cascade classifier (to get less computational time).
So i trained many different cascade classifiers with opencv (opencv_traincascade). The output is good in terms of computational time (0.2-0.3 sec over the entire image, a lot less when launched only over the foreground), so i achieved the goal, let's say. Problem here is the quality of detection: i'm getting a lot of false positive and a lot of false negative. Since the *only* difference between the two methods is the base classifier used in opencv (decision tree or decision stumps, anyway no SVM as far as i understand), so i'm starting to think that my problem could be the base classifier (in some way, hog feature are best separated with hyperplanes i guess).

Of course, the dataset used in libsvm and Opencv is exactly the same, both for training and for testing...for the sake of completeness, i used nearly 9 thousands positive samples and nearly 30 thousands negative samples.

Here my two questions:

- is it possible to change the base weak learner in the opencv_traincascade function? if yes, it the svm one of the possible choices? if the both answers are yes, how can i do such a thing? :)
- are there other computer vision or machine learning libraries that implement the svm as weak classifier and have some methods to train a cascade classifier? (are these libraries suitable to be used in conjuction with opencv?)

thank you in advance as always!

Marco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle a weak classifier can be anything, but the strength of Adaboost related methods is that they are able to obtain good results out of simple classifiers (they are called “weak” for a reason).
Using SVN and Adaboost cascade is a contradiction, as the former has no need to be used in such a framework: it is able to do its job by itself, and the latter is fast just because it takes advantage of weak classifiers.
Furthermore I don’t know of any study about it and OpenCv doesn’t support it: you have to write code by yourself. It is a huge undertaking and probably you won’t get any interesting result.
Anyway if you think that HOG features are more fitted for your task, OpenCv’s traincascade has an option for it, apart from Haar and Lbp.
As to your second question, I’m not sure but quite confident that the answer is negative.
My advice is: try to get the most you can from traincascade, for example try increase the number of samples id you can and compare the results.

Comment: Hi Giusppe, thank you for the answer. Your points are correct, and wrt the use of svm in cascade, i tried to do that because of this paper “Fast Human Detection Using a Cascade of Histograms of Oriented Gradients”, Qiang Zhu, Shai Avidan,Mei-Chen Yeh, Kwang-Ting Cheng, 2006, where they state that it works like a charm! Anyway i was already training  with the HOG feature and opencv; finally i get some results (i increased the dataset - 10k pos, 60k neg) and now the result are "good" (far from perfect but better than before...!). I'll accept your answer! Thx and bye

Answer (score 0):

This [paper](http://elkingarcia.github.io/Papers/MLDM07.pdf) is quite good. It simply says that SVM can be treated as a weak classifier if you use fewer samples to train it (let's say less than half of the training set). The higher the weights the more chance it will be trained by the 'weak-SVM'.

The source code is not widely available unfortunately. If you want a quick prototype, use python scikit learn and see if you can get desirable results before modifying opencv.